# Run a task on shutdown natively in windows

Tags: windows-xp

I'm trying to find a way to run a  command on shutdown on a windows XP system. I've got a task i would prefer to be ended gracefully (and there's a command that would let me do it). While i can run a command at boot up or log on, i can't seem to do so at shutdown. Having a batch file for shutdown as opposed to the button isn't a solution since i'd have to make sure anyone who shuts down the system knows, and i won't be onsite most of the time.

Comment: Does "command" mean 'script' or '.exe'?  That is, do you want a script to execute or an application to run when the computer is shut down?

I don't believe you can (easily) run a program when the user shuts down the computer from Start > Shutdown.  If you want to execute a script, you might want to investigate the Group Policy feature.  Run gpedit.msc and go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown).

Comment: i'd be fine with either. The specific use case is to give virtualbox (which i plan on running in headless mode) a chance to shutdown gracefully should someone switch off the computer 'properly'. This looks like the answer... pending testing at least- so could you put it down as a proper answer so i can select it as the right one, should it be so?

Comment: hmm... also, what format do the scripts need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task Scheduler can run tasks at "user session disconnect" (logging off) however nothing for Shutdown. If there is a user logged in you could use this, otherwise go for the Group Policy thing.